# little endian to decimal conversion

Tags: endianness

Could somebody explain to me how I convert the hex values [3c][f7][3][0] to the number 259900 please? I know it has something to do with little endian but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 bytes starting with the least significant (3c). Second byte you shift 8 bits to left, third - 16 bits etc.